# Android Tensorflow lite Recognizing keywords

Tags: android, tensorflow

how can I use the model from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio in my Android app? How to provide inputs correctly and how to interpret outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow Lite's Task Library has an Audio Classification [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/sound_classification/android/README.md) for Android, which is what you might be looking for. [The guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/audio_classifier) explains how the Java `AudioClassifier` API works.

The Task Library uses YAMNet for audio analysis, which has a pre-trained version on [TFHub](https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/yamnet/classification/tflite/1). If you want to train with your own dataset, please refer to the notebooks mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/audio_classifier).